# loopback How to use ACL REST API? And where does it use?

Tags: loopbackjs

How to use this API? I cannot find any doc.

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/ACL+REST+API

I create user, I create role.

I have ACL in model.json But API does not return anything.

I also found this link but not really helpful tho.

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Using+built-in+models#Usingbuilt-inmodels-Usermodel

Answer (score 1):

this may help:

> By default, the ACL REST API is not exposed. To expose it, add the following >to models.json:
>   "acl": {
>      "public": true,
>      "options": {
>        "base": "ACL"
>      },
>      "dataSource": "db"
>    },